# split in java adds empty space to string array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

im trying to split a string using a REGEX. The problem is that when splitting it adds an empty space to my String Array

```
  public static String[] line;

  line=this.classMetodos.split(meth.regexMethHead);
```

meth.regexMethHead being the regular expresion i want to split with.

the output given is the next one:

Metodos Contenido [0]:

Metodos Contenido [1]: {lol;}

Metodos Contenido [2]: {lol;}}

the output wanted is:

Metodos Contenido [0]: {lol;}

Metodos Contenido [1]: {lol;}}

Regex used

Regex used:

```
 public static String regexAccess = "(public|private|\\s*)";

    public static String regexStatic = "(static|\\s*)";

    public static String regexReturnType = "(String|double|void)";

    public static String regexMethName = "([a-z]|[A-Z])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*";

    public static String regexVariableName = "([a-z]|[A-Z])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*";

    public static String regexString = "\"([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*\"";

    public static String regexArgs="(\\(\\)|\\(("+regexReturnType+"\\s*"+regexVariableName+")\\))";

    public static String regexMethContent="\\{(.*|\\n*|\\t*)*\\}";

   //complete regular expression 
    public static String regexMethHead = regexAccess +
            "\\s*"+ 
            regexStatic+
            "\\s*"+
            regexReturnType+
            "\\s*"+
            regexMethName+
            "\\s*"+
            regexArgs;
```

Input String

```
public static String meth= "public static void jenny(String lolito){\n\t lol;\n\n\t}";
    public static String meth2= " public void Lolamer(String jeny){\n\t lol;\n\n\t}";
    public static String variables ="static String e =\"lol\";";
    public static String pseudoClass="public class torito{"+"\n"+variables+"\n"+
            meth+"\n"+meth2+"}";
    public static String regexClassName = "([a-z]|[A-Z])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*";
    public static String regexClassContent="\\{(.*|\\n*|\\t*)*\\}";
    public static String regexCLass="^(public|private|\\s*)\\s*class\\s+"+
            regexClassName+""+
            regexClassContent+"";
```

Keep in mind my regex and String come from other class and im pulling them to make the split in another class

THANKS

Comment: Provide input string and regex used.

Comment: just edited the post with the input string and regex used!! help!!

Comment: Let me introduce you to my friend, [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: thanks!! gonna read about it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that when you want to split, if the expression you want to split starts with some value in the REGEX it asumes that theres something there (before the regex wich is going to use to  split), so thats why it was saving an empty space at the begining.